# Logic task, a square divided in smaller squares with a logic rule

Tags: matrix, logic, task

a square is separated in 25 smaller squares, you have to put numbers in every smaller square from 1-25 so that the sum of the small squares in the axes of symmetry is 65. I need help with the code

the link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwCNA.jpg

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried so far.  What language are you using?  Do you have any experience writing code in that language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Search in Wikipedia has several algorithms for generating magic squares**

A simple Java program to do this, can be easily rewritten in any language:

/*
* Magic Square
*/

```
int order = 5;

for (int row = 0; row < order; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < order; col++) {
        int rowMatrix = (((order + 1) / 2 + row + col) % order);
        int colMatrix = (((order + 1) / 2 + row + order - col - 1) %
order) + 1;
        System.out.print(((rowMatrix * order) + colMatrix) + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
```

Comment: I need to regenerate the matrix, the numbers should change positions, to fulfill the task, so I think that at the end of the program we should add an: if(x=='Y') for the matrix numbers to change positions and for:  else (x=='N') to end the program can you help me?